# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class error occurring at execution time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
public class Test{
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;


@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    baseUrl = "https:gmail.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void gmalLogin() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("sunil.wali");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Trelleborg@123");
    driver.findElement(By.id("log_in")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);

}


@AfterTest
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();

    }
}
```

}

Result: 
Before execution, window() method is undefined in setup method while TestNG installed successfully in system.

After Execution, Result -
org.testng.TestNGException:

Cannot instantiate class Test

```
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)

    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)

    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)

    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)

    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is only possible when you provide more information like how you are running your test class. programatically, via eclips or from command line?

This exception occurs with testNG only when test classpath is not accesible by testNG.